# Live code not updating - Js requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, laravel

The network in developer tools shows that the selection is being made and gives me a preview of what is the correct code but the actual live code does not update when the select option is changed, any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix the issue so that the live code changes?

PHP:

```
   $batsmenQuery = Batsmen::where('approved', '=', 1);

   switch ($request->SortbyList){
        case 0:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('name', 'DESC');
            break;
        case 1:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
            break;
        case 2:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('hs', 'ASC');
            break;
        case 3:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('hs', 'DESC');
            break;
            default:
                $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('name', 'DESC');


    }

    $batsmen= $batsmenQuery->paginate(40);
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="sort">
            <select name="SortbyList" id="SortBy">
                <option value="0">A to Z</option>
                <option value="1">Z to A</option>
                <option value="2">Highest Score</option>
                <option value="3">Lowest Score</option>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


     $('#SortBy').on('change', function(e) {
         $.ajax({
             url: "{{route('search.index')}}", // This is the url you make the request
             data: {SortbyList: this.value}, // Here you can send to the server the info you want in this case is only the value for the selected item
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (result) {

                 if (result) {
                     $("#SortBy").empty();  //This erase all the preview values
                     var new_options = '';
                     //This loop create the new values
                     $.each(result, function (k, v) {
                         new_options += '<option value="' + v.value + '">' + v.name + '</option>'
                     });
                     //Now we have all the values we can put on the select
                     $("#SortBy").append(new_options);


                 }

             }
         });
     });
```

Comment: Judging by your code example It should work. Without a working example or more code it's not easy to diagnose.

Comment: are there errors in the console?

Comment: Showing No errors in console